# Can Sass evaluate strings that contain mathematical expressions?

Tags: sass

I'm trying to create a function which will output a list of numbers based on an expression given to it.

Does anyone know how I can pass an expression through a function and have it evaluated within the function?

This is what I have so far:

```
@function patt($expression, $b: 10) {
    $result: ();
    @for $i from 1 through 10 {
        $result: append($result, unquote($expression));
    }
    @return $result;
}
```

Example usage:

```
$list: patt('$i * $b + 2');
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Presumably the expression is being treated as a string within the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Sass does not have an *eval* function.  The closest you can get is by using the `call` function.

```
@function my-expression($x, $y) {
  @return $x * $y + 2;
}

@function patt($expression, $b: 10) {
    $result: ();
    @for $i from 1 through 10 {
        $result: append($result, call($expression, $i, $b));
    }
    @return $result;
}

$list: patt('my-expression'); // 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82 92 102
```

Comment: Oh that's a shame. Thanks for the suggestion. Would it work if I created a custom sass function in ruby?

Comment: I didn't know if the problem was with SASS or with Ruby functions in general. I tried building a custom function but I couldn't evaluate the string that was being passed in.

Comment: I already told you that Sass cannot evaluate strings.  If you want to perform arithmetic, you have to have numeric types (integer, float, length, etc.).

Comment: Do you think I didn't read your post? I can create a function as a custom SASS function in Ruby which to me is different.