# Dynamically call mixin/function in SASS to DRY up redundant code block - some sort of eval() functionality?

Tags: css, ruby, sass, metaprogramming

I have a number of mixins in my Sass code that are used to generate media-queried and non-media-queried properties:

```
@mixin create-responsive-font-size($breakpoint, $font-size) {
  $breakpoints-map: map-deep-get($config, breakpoints);

  // TODO: abstract into reusable function
  @if $breakpoint == none {
    @include create-font-size($font-size);
  }
  @else if map-has-key($breakpoints-map, $breakpoint) {
    $mapped-breakpoint: map-get($breakpoints-map, $breakpoint);

    @media screen and (min-width: $mapped-breakpoint) {
      @include create-font-size($font-size);
    }
  }
}

@mixin create-font-size($font-size) {
  // irrelevant other code here
  ...

  font-size: $px-font-size;
  font-size: $rem-font-size;
}
```

I'd really like to DRY up that former mixin to abstract the `@if/@else` portion, as I have a number of mixins that use that exact same logic. However, the logic within the block isn't always the same - sometimes another mixin is called (as in that first example), sometimes a property is set directly, as such:

```
@mixin create-responsive-line-height($breakpoint, $line-height) {
  $breakpoints-map: map-deep-get($config, breakpoints);

  $line-height: $line-height !default;

  // TODO: abstract into reusable function
  @if $breakpoint == none {
    line-height: $line-height;
  }
  @else if map-has-key($breakpoints-map, $breakpoint) {
    $mapped-breakpoint: map-get($breakpoints-map, $breakpoint);

    @media screen and (min-width: $mapped-breakpoint) {
      line-height: $line-height;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, it'd be cool to abstract that `@if/@else` in such a way that I could dynamically pass in a command to the new helper mixin and execute it by unquoting and running some form of `eval`, much like one would in Javascript:

```
@mixin invoke-dynamic($breakpoint, $command) {
  $breakpoints-map: map-deep-get($config, breakpoints);

  @if $breakpoint == none {
    call(unquote($command));
  }
  @else if map-has-key($breakpoints-map, $breakpoint) {
    $mapped-breakpoint: map-get($breakpoints-map, $breakpoint);

    @media screen and (min-width: $mapped-breakpoint) {
      call(unquote($command));
    }
  }
}
```

Which would be invoked as such, assuming we rewrote the previous two mixin examples:

```
@mixin create-responsive-font-size($breakpoint, $font-size) {
  @include invoke-dynamic($breakpoint, "@include create-font-size($font-size);");
}

@mixin create-responsive-line-height($breakpoint, $line-height) {
  @include invoke-dynamic($breakpoint, "line-height: $line-height;");
}
```

I would also settle for similar functionality even if I had to wrap every sub-call in another mixin to avoid the direct property setting (as with the `line-height` example).

This seems to be fairly advanced usage of Sass, and I couldn't find any resources on achieving such a thing. Additionally, there appear to be some issues even with attempting to dynamically invoke mixins, making my attempts even more fruitless.

Totally open to any suggestions as far as approaches or code reorganization for an approach like this!

Comment: Alternate duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810212/can-sass-evaluate-strings-that-contain-mathematical-expressions

Comment: I don't know that I'd say this is a duplicate - using first-class functions in Sass isn't the same thing as being able to `unquote` and `eval()` a string. Somewhat similar functionally, but I'm not asking the same thing.

Comment: i don't know what you think unquote does, but it has nothing to do with your question in any way shape or form.

Comment: That's part of what I was asking: would `unquote` be necessary to interpolate and execute/`eval` an arbitrary statement? In JS, `eval` is run directly on a quoted string, but in Sass, I'm unsure. Regardless, despite your unnecessarily confrontational replies (both here and in that origin post), I'll assume that post is still accurate and that there's no form of `eval` available in Sass, and will pursue another approach.